# Why is the Epstein drive called that?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

Of course it was named after its inventor...but how?  His first successful test propelled him into deep space for several hours at an acceleration that was almost fatal.  Nobody human was going to run across the salvage.  He was a lone tinkerer, not working with ground control on a large project.  Then one day he goes missing, never to return.

How did the people he left behind know about and replicate his accomplishment?

Comment: In the TV series, the drive goes on for weeks, and the accelerometer breaks at 10g ;-).

Comment: Did you read the books?  It's quite clear.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I expect a significant proportion of people who have seen the expanse TV show have not read; myself included.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What I recall from a YouTube clip I've seen of the first, fatal test of Epstein's new drive, he was in communication with his wife (on Mars) just before applying power, and had left (copies of) his notes and data behind with her.  This left her in full ownership of the Epstein drive patents (once they issued).

Comment: Also in the novella 'Drive'

Comment: Thanks, I haven't yet managed to read any of the books or stories.

Comment: Somehow I remembered (from the show) him being estranged from his wife.  I must have been conflating that with something else...maybe Alex.

Comment: One clip is [here](https://youtu.be/1lS_WxQ3zeU), with Spanish subtitles. The writers are mean here because they tell it from the first person perspective but without plot armor.  "I never gave Katy a child. But she had the plans for my drive. It'd make her rich for the rest of her life. Because with my drive, the *Epstein* drive, Mars would be able to move outward. Behind the asteroids. Colonize the belt. And remake the Solar System. My drive would give us the edge we needed to finally break free from Earth. And build a new world for ourselves."